# How to make sure the completion of two process in c#

Tags: c#, .net, process, console-application

I have an application as shown below which is triggered by another console application by a`Process.Start()` method(ie by two arguments) in a loop by two times.Here there is a third method `Lastmethod();` which will send mails contains the out put of `startfirst();` and  `startsecond();`.But i don't know how to trigger the third method after the completion first two methods. i set two flags, but it is showing some times correct and some time wrong result by sending mails of partial results(without the completion of first two methods)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool first = false;
    bool second = false;
    if (args[0] == "test")
    {
        startfirst();//time consuming process which will trigger internal child process
        first = true;
    }
    if (args[0] == "finish")
    {
        startsecond();//time consuming process which will trigger internal child process
        second =true;
    }
    if(first && second)
    {
        Lastmethod();
    }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void Lastmethod()
    {
        //sending mail of the out put of startfirst(); and  startsecond(); method
    }

    private static void startsecond()
    {
        //time consuming first operation
    }

    private static void startfirst()
    {
        //time consuming second operation
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
suppose if iam starting multiple say 10 same process like

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
Process.Start("Process.exe");
}
```

how will i check the completion? Shall i use `WaitForExit`() here

Comment: Both of your condition statements check the same argument, is this correct?

Comment: I'm guessing (or hoping) he quickly wrote this sample code to try to visualize his problem.

Comment: Do you use `Process.Start()` in this code as well? Then you have to wait for exit. It sometimes works because the process finishes fast enough, while at other times it takes longer. Please read [ask] and create a [mcve], which you should know after 1750+ reputation.

Comment: @Fishcake my starting application taking arguments from database and executing Process.Start() in a loop,so it is sending two arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you start a process, you can wait till it is finished by two options:

1. The Process.WaitForExit() method.
2. The Process.Exited event.

After the process is finished, you can process the result and use it to send your e-mail.

If you want to wait per process, modify your code like this. Al processes will wait till the previous is finished:

```
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var process = Process.Start("Process.exe");
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

If you want to wait till ALL processes are finished, try this. All processes will run at the same time.

```
var processes = new List<Process>();
for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var process = Process.Start("Process.exe");
    processes.Add(process);
}
foreach(var process in processes)
    proccess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Yeah but OP only explains they _start this application_ through Process.Start(), which is irrelevant. Unless they use Process.Start() in this code as well, which they do not show...

Comment: @CodeCaster: You are correct. Right now I assume he DOES use Process.Start in his code, since he mentions it as part of his problem. If it turns out I was wrong, I will remove my answer.

Comment: I edited my question like suppose if iam starting multiple say 10 same process like 

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
    Process.Start("Process.exe");
    }
how will i check the completioon

Comment: shall i use WaitForExit() here?

Comment: It's called `WaitForExit` not `WaitTillExit`.

Comment: @RenéVogt: Thanx! my mistake! Corrected it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
var processes = new List<Process>();
for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
    processes.Add(Process.Start("process.exe"));

foreach (Process p in processes)
    p.WaitForExit();
```

Please take the time to read the [documentation of the `Process` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) before asking.